# numerical math problem

Tags: problem-solving

How to divide Rs.10,000 to four persons proportionately?
 ( let's say  A invested Rs 3,200 B Rs 5,700 C Rs 8400 and D Rs 9,900 respectively.

Comment: Your question has the answer implicitly embedded in it! The keyword is "proportionately". What are the fractions of the total investment of each partner ?

Comment: Hi..Mr.Sharat, Well thanks for the concern.

Comment: Actually it's a general math query. I've mentioned enough details there.I'm not being able to mathmatically solve it . pls help.

Answer (score 1):

Let the individual investments be $x_A$, $x_B$, $x_C$ and $x_D$. The total investment is $x_A+ x_B+x_C+x_D$.

So Investor A's fraction is $f_A=\frac{x_A}{x_A+ x_B+x_C+x_D}$ and likewise for the other investors.

Multiply $10000 by each of the fractions to determine the amount each of them is owed.

Comment: Really thankful. I'll follow the procedure and try to solve.